# Dynamically add reactive plots to web page using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do something very similar to what is explained here
[dynamically add plots to web page using shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875786/dynamically-add-plots-to-web-page-using-shiny).

However I need the equivalent call to the plot function inside renderPlot (server.r:line 28) to be reactive, to be called only when input changes. In my setup I have a list with the function names that I need to call.

I have provided a sample code of want I mean and the attempt of using the reactive callback.

```
for (i in 1:length(plot_list)) {
  local({
    my_i <- i
    plotname <- paste("plot_fn_name", my_i, sep="")
    output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
      args <- list(input$arg1, input$arg2, input$arg3)
      fn <- reactive({plot_list[[my_i]](args)})
      #p <- do.call(fn, args)
      p <- fn()
      print(p)
    })
  })
}
```

Any thougts on how to achieve this?
Thanks.