# How to allow for dynamic amount of file inputs from user in R shiny?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I am looking to allow the user to enter the quantity of files they are interested in uploading, and then having the UI react to give that many file input buttons.

I am not certain how to do this. Even once this is completed, I am not certain how best to handle this dynamic amount of variables.

```
#ui.R

  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Upload your files"),
    fluidRow(

      column(3, wellPanel(
        numericInput("user_num_2", 
                     label = h4("Number of Old Files"), 
                     value = 1)
      )),

      column(4, wellPanel(
        # This outputs the dynamic UI component
        uiOutput("ui1")
      ))
    ),
    fluidRow(

      column(3, wellPanel(
        numericInput("user_num_2", 
                     label = h4("Number of New Files"), 
                     value = 1)
      )),


      column(4, wellPanel(
        # This outputs the dynamic UI component
        uiOutput("ui2")
      ))
    ),
    fluidRow(

      column(3, wellPanel(

        selectInput("input_type", 
                    label = h4("Geography Assignment"), 
                    c("Zip", "County", "Zip-County", "Custom Assignment"
                    )
        )
      ))
    )
  ))
```

So a user can enter how many file upload buttons they want. The idea is to merge them all together. The `multiple` option would not work because these files could be in different locations.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: you should include a reproducible example of what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: A minimal shiny code would be useful but the question is clear enough IMO.

Comment: @MLavoie I hope you don't find this argumentative, but if I was capable of doing that, I would not need to ask for help.

Comment: Not sure how big your files are, but quickest solution i can think of is to put them all in the same location and use the multiple argument. Much cleaner than having multiple variable fileInputs...

Comment: @NBATrends that has worked in the past, though this particular project would not permit that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I hope you like this. Idea came from this post: [Shiny R renderPrint in loop usinf RenderUI only update the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718436/shiny-r-renderprint-in-loop-usinf-renderui-only-update-the-output)

You can easily store the objects created from each of the file inputs in a list to be used for further analysis.

## Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$fileInputs=renderUI({
    html_ui = " "
    for (i in 1:input$nfiles){
      html_ui <- paste0(html_ui, fileInput(paste0("file",i), label=paste0("file",i)))
    }
    HTML(html_ui)
  })

})
```

## UI

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Variable files'),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("nfiles", "number of files", value = 2, min = 1, step = 1),
    uiOutput("fileInputs")
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

Some explanation, shiny operates through HTML. If you run the line of code below in the console you will see the logic behind creating the object `html_ui` that can hold a variable number of these HTML elements.

```
fileInput(paste0("file",1), label=paste0("file",1))

# <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
#   <label>file1</label>
#   <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file"/>
#     <div id="file1_progress" class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress">
#       <div class="progress-bar"></div>
#   </div>
# </div>
```