# Shiny delete table row

Tags: r, shiny

I want to delete the last row of a table using an action button. I have tried to follow this post [Shiny: dynamically add/ remove textInput rows based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228757/shiny-dynamically-add-remove-textinput-rows-based-on-index) 
but I don't know how to apply the idea to my particular case.

A minimal reproducible example

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(numericInput("c1","Example", NA),
           actionButton("update", "Update Table"),
           br(),  br(),
           actionButton("reset", "Clear")
  ),

  mainPanel( tableOutput("example")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # stores the current data frame, called by values() and set by 
  values(new_data_table)
  values <- reactiveVal(data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3))

  # update values table on button click
  observeEvent(input$update,{

    old_values <- values()

    A_new <- input$c1
    B_new <- A_new + 2
    C_new <- A_new + B_new

    new_values <- data.frame(A=A_new, B=B_new, C=C_new)

    # attach the new line to the old data frame here:
    new_df <- rbind(old_values, new_values)

    #store the result in values variable
    values(new_df)

    #reset the numeric input to NA  
    updateNumericInput(session, "c1", "Example", NA)

  })
 #delete last row
   deleteEntry <- observeEvent(input$reset,{
                 #.... 
 })

  #Print the content of values$df
  output$example <- renderTable({  return(values())  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Actually I don't know how to call the last row of my interactive data frame. I have tried something like values() <- values[nrow(values())-1] but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

EDITED

Following the suggestion below I have modified the deleteEntry function and now it works.

```
 ##delete last row
   deleteEntry <- observeEvent(input$reset,{
                 values( values()[-nrow(values()),])
 })
```

Comment: What about `values( values()[nrow(values())-1,]) `?

Comment: or `values(values()[-nrow(values()),])`

Comment: Thanks @HubertL, the solution is values(values()[-nrow(values()),]). I have edited the code including your suggestion. Regards.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected.

Comment: But I don't know how mark my question as solved.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question to add the answer, instead you could have created an answer, that you mark as accepted

Comment: Well, it was your answer.

Comment: I think it is OK to create an answer from a comment if the commenter does not seem to want to do it and if you mention their name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the last row of a `data.frame` as a `reactiveVal` , use this syntax:

```
values(values()[-nrow(values()),])
```

Comment: What about reactiveValues? Can I use the same syntax?

Comment: with `my <- reactiveValues(values=data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3))` you would do `my$values <- my$values[-nrow(my$values),]` which may be a bit more readable.