# Adding and removing tabPanel by clicking buttons in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to design a Shiny app such that a user can click on buttons to add or remove a `tabPanel`. I've been able to do this successfully with the code below, but there is a problem. In the code below every time the user clicks on `Add L2` or `Remove L2`, the entire panel is recreated, thus resetting all inputs in each `tabPanel`. This is problematic because the goal is for the user to dynamically add `tabPanels` and save their inputs. Is there any way to do this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3, fixed=T,
      h3("L2 Machine"),
      actionButton('moreL2', tags$b('Add L2')),
      actionButton('lessL2', tags$b('Remove L2')),
      uiOutput('panelset')
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  more <- reactiveValues(i=1)
  less <- reactiveValues(i=1)
  observe({
    input$moreL2
    isolate({
      more$i <- more$i + 1
    })
  })
  observe({
    input$lessL2
    isolate({
      less$i <- less$i + 1
    })
  })

  output$panelset <- renderUI({
    if(less$i > more$i) less$i <- more$i

    n <- seq(max(more$i - less$i + 1, 1))
    lapply(n, function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        title = paste0('Pan', i),
        numericInput(paste0('L2amount', i), 'Select L2 Amount', value = 0),
        selectInput(paste0('L2type', i), 'Select L2 Type', c('Percent', 'Absolute')),
        dateRangeInput(paste0('L2daterange',i), 'Select Adjustment Period', 
          start='01-01-2010', end='01-12-2015'))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think the key is to render each tabPanel separately. If you know the max number of panels in advance, you can create that many `uiOutput` and only render the new ones as needed.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020810/dynamically-creating-tabs-with-plots-in-shiny-without-re-creating-existing-tabs/), without the deleting part. But it would be very easy to write a function that deletes tabPanels. If you'd like some further details, I could adapt this to your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @K.Rohde, I'll take a look at the code and see if I can adapt it. I'm not too familiar with JavaScript so that might be a bit of a challenge for me.