# R - markdown how to print list of dataframes to "Tabbed sections"

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmltools

According bookdown documentation in 3.3, there is functionality to hide chunks in to the tabs. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html

I occasionally use it, but I can't figure out how to do it if I print dataframes via loops. Imagine that I have similar dataframe.

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
    nr = seq(1, 8)
  )
```

I split it via id column to following list

```
t_list <-
  lapply(split(df, df$id), function(df) {

    id <- unique(df$id)

    htmltools::tagList(
      htmltools::h4("TASK"),

      htmltools::tags$table(
        tableHTML::tableHTML(
          login,
          rownames = F)
      )
    )

  })
```

Expected output is that each id will be in separate tab, but it doesn't work with following code. Please not that I would like to use htmltools in loop part since I enhance tables via javascript.

````
### TEST

```{r}
htmltools::tagList(t_list)
```
````

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631642/creating-dynamic-tabs-in-rmarkdown)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `imap`:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

rmd_tabsets <- function(.data) {

  # first empty header to intialize tabsets
  cat("#### { .tabset .unlisted .unnumbered}", "\n\n", sep = "")

  purrr::imap(.data, function(.x, .y) {
    cat("##### TASK ", .y, "\n\n", sep = "")
    print(tableHTML::tableHTML(.x))
    cat("\n\n")
  })
  # close with empty header to stop tabsets
  cat("#### {.unlisted .unnumbered}")
}

df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
    nr = seq(1, 8)
  )

df_list <- split(df, df$id)

rmd_tabsets(df_list)
```
````

[image]