# R Shiny: Isolate dynamic output within dynamic tabs

Tags: r, dynamic, tabs, shiny, output

I am trying to create an app where you choose certain inputs in the sidebar, and when you click on a button it will show the results in a separate tab. I created a tiny example that you can use below.

In this example, you choose 4 letters in the sidebar and if you click on the button, it dynamically creates a separate tab with text output. However, when you change the letters and click on the button again, all previous tabs will update with the new results. I'd like to isolate the result in each tab but I don't know how to do that. I tried to do this by using different output names (see variable `summaryname` in the server) but it doesn't work.

This example only uses text output, but my real app also uses tables and plots.

I'd appreciate any help!

**ui**:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_1", label = "First choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "H", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_2", label = "Second choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "E", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_3", label = "Third choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "L", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_4", label = "Fourth choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "P", multiple = FALSE),
                 actionButton(inputId = "goButton", label = "Go!")

    ),
    mainPanel(width = 8,
              tabPanel("Result", fluid = TRUE,
                       uiOutput(outputId = "tabs"),
                       conditionalPanel(condition="input.level == 1",
                                        HTML("<font size = 3><strong>Select your inputs and click 'Go!'.</strong></font>")
                       ),
                       conditionalPanel(condition="input.level != 1",
                                        uiOutput(outputId = "summary")
                       )
              )
    )
  )
)
```

**Server**:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$tabs <- renderUI({

    Tabs <- as.list(rep(0, input$goButton+1))

    for (i in 0:length(Tabs)){
      Tabs[i] = lapply(paste("Results", i, sep = " "), tabPanel, value = i)
    }

    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(Tabs, id = "level"))
  })

  output$summary <- renderUI({
    summary <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {paste("<strong>", "Summary:", "</strong>", "<br>",
                                                    "You chose the following letters:", input$choice_1, input$choice_2, input$choice_3, input$choice_4, "." ,"<br>",
                                                    "Thank you for helping me!")
    })

    summaryname <- paste("Summary", input$goButton+1, sep = "")

    output[[summaryname]] <- renderText({summary()})
    htmlOutput(summaryname)
  })

}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm experiencing problems now when I try to get a navbarPage layout around the code. Somehow, the results of the dynamic tabs get displayed wrong (and again not isolated properly). I only changed the ui, but I included the server just in case.

**ui**:

```
ui <- navbarPage("Shiny",

  # Important! : JavaScript functionality to add the Tabs
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
                             /* In coherence with the original Shiny way, tab names are created with random numbers. 
                             To avoid duplicate IDs, we collect all generated IDs.  */
                             var hrefCollection = [];

                             Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('addTabToTabset', function(message){
                             var hrefCodes = [];
                             /* Getting the right tabsetPanel */
                             var tabsetTarget = document.getElementById(message.tabsetName);

                             /* Iterating through all Panel elements */
                             for(var i = 0; i < message.titles.length; i++){
                             /* Creating 6-digit tab ID and check, whether it was already assigned. */
                             do {
                             hrefCodes[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
                             } 
                             while(hrefCollection.indexOf(hrefCodes[i]) != -1);
                             hrefCollection = hrefCollection.concat(hrefCodes[i]);

                             /* Creating node in the navigation bar */
                             var navNode = document.createElement('li');
                             var linkNode = document.createElement('a');

                             linkNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.titles[i]));
                             linkNode.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'tab');
                             linkNode.setAttribute('data-value', message.titles[i]);
                             linkNode.setAttribute('href', '#tab-' + hrefCodes[i]);

                             navNode.appendChild(linkNode);
                             tabsetTarget.appendChild(navNode);
                             };

                             /* Move the tabs content to where they are normally stored. Using timeout, because
                             it can take some 20-50 millis until the elements are created. */ 
                             setTimeout(function(){
                             var creationPool = document.getElementById('creationPool').childNodes;
                             var tabContainerTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content')[0];

                             /* Again iterate through all Panels. */
                             for(var i = 0; i < creationPool.length; i++){
                             var tabContent = creationPool[i];
                             tabContent.setAttribute('id', 'tab-' + hrefCodes[i]);

                             tabContainerTarget.appendChild(tabContent);
                             };
                             }, 100);
                             });
                             "))),
  # End Important

  tabPanel("Statistics"),

  tabPanel("Summary",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_1", label = "First choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "H", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_2", label = "Second choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "E", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_3", label = "Third choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "L", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_4", label = "Fourth choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "P", multiple = FALSE),
                 actionButton("goCreate", "Go create a new Tab!")
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabset",
                  tabPanel("InitialPanel1", "Some text here to show this is InitialPanel1",
                           textOutput("creationInfo"),
                           # Important! : 'Freshly baked' tabs first enter here.
                           uiOutput("creationPool", style = "display: none;")
                           # End Important
                  )
      )
    )
    )
  )
)
```

**Server**:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Important! : creationPool should be hidden to avoid elements flashing before they are moved.
  #              But hidden elements are ignored by shiny, unless this option below is set.
  output$creationPool <- renderUI({})
  outputOptions(output, "creationPool", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  # End Important

  # Important! : This is the make-easy wrapper for adding new tabPanels.
  addTabToTabset <- function(Panels, tabsetName){
    titles <- lapply(Panels, function(Panel){return(Panel$attribs$title)})
    Panels <- lapply(Panels, function(Panel){Panel$attribs$title <- NULL; return(Panel)})

    output$creationPool <- renderUI({Panels})
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "addTabToTabset", message = list(titles = titles, tabsetName = tabsetName))
  }
  # End Important 

  # From here: Just for demonstration
  output$creationInfo <- renderText({
    paste0("The next tab will be named: Results ", input$goCreate + 1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$goCreate, {
    nr <- input$goCreate

    newTabPanels <- list(
      tabPanel(paste0("NewTab ", nr),

               htmlOutput(paste0("Html_text", nr)),
               actionButton(paste0("Button", nr), "Some new button!"), 
               textOutput(paste0("Text", nr))
      )
    )

    output[[paste0("Html_text", nr)]] <- renderText({
        paste("<strong>", "Summary:", "</strong>", "<br>",
              "You chose the following letters:", isolate(input$choice_1), isolate(input$choice_2), isolate(input$choice_3), isolate(input$choice_4), "." ,"<br>",
              "Thank you for helping me!")
    })

    addTabToTabset(newTabPanels, "mainTabset")
  })
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020810/dynamically-creating-tabs-with-plots-in-shiny-without-re-creating-existing-tabs/) would help?

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I tried implementing it with my example script, but unfortunately I still got the same problem. I can't identify what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the code given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020810/dynamically-creating-tabs-with-plots-in-shiny-without-re-creating-existing-tabs/) with the code you provided I was able to produce the desired result.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Important! : JavaScript functionality to add the Tabs
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
                             /* In coherence with the original Shiny way, tab names are created with random numbers. 
                             To avoid duplicate IDs, we collect all generated IDs.  */
                             var hrefCollection = [];

                             Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('addTabToTabset', function(message){
                             var hrefCodes = [];
                             /* Getting the right tabsetPanel */
                             var tabsetTarget = document.getElementById(message.tabsetName);

                             /* Iterating through all Panel elements */
                             for(var i = 0; i < message.titles.length; i++){
                             /* Creating 6-digit tab ID and check, whether it was already assigned. */
                             do {
                             hrefCodes[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
                             } 
                             while(hrefCollection.indexOf(hrefCodes[i]) != -1);
                             hrefCollection = hrefCollection.concat(hrefCodes[i]);

                             /* Creating node in the navigation bar */
                             var navNode = document.createElement('li');
                             var linkNode = document.createElement('a');

                             linkNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message.titles[i]));
                             linkNode.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'tab');
                             linkNode.setAttribute('data-value', message.titles[i]);
                             linkNode.setAttribute('href', '#tab-' + hrefCodes[i]);

                             navNode.appendChild(linkNode);
                             tabsetTarget.appendChild(navNode);
                             };

                             /* Move the tabs content to where they are normally stored. Using timeout, because
                             it can take some 20-50 millis until the elements are created. */ 
                             setTimeout(function(){
                             var creationPool = document.getElementById('creationPool').childNodes;
                             var tabContainerTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content')[0];

                             /* Again iterate through all Panels. */
                             for(var i = 0; i < creationPool.length; i++){
                             var tabContent = creationPool[i];
                             tabContent.setAttribute('id', 'tab-' + hrefCodes[i]);

                             tabContainerTarget.appendChild(tabContent);
                             };
                             }, 100);
                             });
                             "))),
  # End Important
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_1", label = "First choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "H", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_2", label = "Second choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "E", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_3", label = "Third choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "L", multiple = FALSE),
                 selectInput(inputId = "choice_4", label = "Fourth choice:",
                             choices = LETTERS, selected = "P", multiple = FALSE),
                 actionButton(inputId = "goCreate", label = "Go!")

    ),
    mainPanel(width = 8,
  tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabset", 
               tabPanel("InitialPanel1", "Some Text here to show this is InitialPanel1")
  ),

  # Important! : 'Freshly baked' tabs first enter here.
  uiOutput("creationPool", style = "display: none;")
  # End Important
    ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Important! : creationPool should be hidden to avoid elements flashing before they are moved.
  #              But hidden elements are ignored by shiny, unless this option below is set.
  output$creationPool <- renderUI({})
  outputOptions(output, "creationPool", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  # End Important

  # Important! : This is the make-easy wrapper for adding new tabPanels.
  addTabToTabset <- function(Panels, tabsetName){
    titles <- lapply(Panels, function(Panel){return(Panel$attribs$title)})
    Panels <- lapply(Panels, function(Panel){Panel$attribs$title <- NULL; return(Panel)})

    output$creationPool <- renderUI({Panels})
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "addTabToTabset", message = list(titles = titles, tabsetName = tabsetName))
  }
  # End Important 

  # From here: Just for demonstration
  output$creationInfo <- renderText({
    paste0("The next tab will be named NewTab", input$goCreate + 1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$goCreate, {
    nr <- input$goCreate
    newTabPanels <- list(
      tabPanel(paste0("Result", nr), 
               # actionButton(paste0("Button", nr), "Some new button!"), 
               htmlOutput(paste0("Text", nr))
      )
    )

    output[[paste0("Text", nr)]] <- renderText({
      paste("<strong>", "Summary:", "</strong>", "<br>",
            "You chose the following letters:", isolate(input$choice_1), isolate(input$choice_2), isolate(input$choice_3), isolate(input$choice_4), "." ,"<br>",
            "Thank you for helping me!")
    })

    addTabToTabset(newTabPanels, "mainTabset")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you SO much, it works perfectly. I see that my mistake was to not include isolate(). Thank you!

Comment: I have one follow up question: do you know how I can implement a navbarPage in this framework? My final app needs multiple screens. When I try it my tabPanels open the wrong way; they open in a blank screen instead of in the tabsetPanel.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? I don't think I understand your question properly.

Comment: I just edited my post with a new ui and server so you can reproduce it. Thank you for trying to help me again!

Comment: The navbarPage seems to mess up the javascript functionality that was added. You might want to post another question for that.