# Update DataTable dynamically with navbar

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

**Context**

I'm building an app whith Rshiny. I created a dynamic navbar. Now, i would like to insert a datatable at each navbar's item (tabPanel). But i don't want to create a table per item in navbar. So i would like to know if it's possible to create only 1 table which update itself with the navbar's selected item ??

**Code to create dynamical navbar**

```
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("paper"),title="test",
      tabPanel(uiOutput('mytabs'))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$mytabs = renderUI({
      nTabs = length(unique(iris$Species))
      myTabs = lapply(unique(iris$Species)[1:nTabs], tabPanel)
      do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
    })
  }
))
```

Now i woulk like to display `datatable(subset(iris,Species=="value of navbar"))` at each navbar's item

Can someone explain me how to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020810/dynamically-creating-tabs-with-plots-in-shiny-without-re-creating-existing-tabs/), you can define a function and call it as below. Note that csv button will only work in a browser.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

runApp(list(
   ui = fluidPage(
        navbarPage(theme=shinytheme("paper"),title="test",
           tabPanel(uiOutput('mytabs'))
     )
  ),
server = function(input, output, session){

createTabs <- function(species_r){
  tabPanel(title = paste("Data", species_r, sep=" "), 
           datatable(subset(iris,Species==species_r),rownames = FALSE,
                     extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('copy', 'csv',I('colvis'))))
           )
}

output$mytabs = renderUI({
  nTabs = length(unique(iris$Species))
  myTabs = lapply(unique(iris$Species)[1:nTabs], createTabs)
  do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
  })
 }
))
```

Comment: I didn't get where do i have to insert it. an you please tell me ?

Comment: Do you know how can i insert an observeevent to choose columns i want to display ?

Comment: observeEvent is [Event handler](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/observeEvent.html), I think you need [Checkbox Group Input Control](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/checkboxGroupInput.html). If I am correct let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes, when i display my tables, there are too many columns so the display is ugly so i would like the user to be able to chose columns he wants to display.

Comment: In that case, can I suggest [4. ColVis](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) from DT package.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is ok now !!

Comment: you are most welcome. I update the answer with csv and copy for future reader.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why but when i click on copy or csv, nothing happens. It works when i open the app in browser.

Comment: I think because it uses JS library or may be a compatibility issue  I don't know frankly. So yes **csv** only work in a browser. **copy** work like Ctrl+C then you have to open a new Excel sheet or word and Press Ctrl+V or Paste for example.