# Dynamically display images from upload in Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

This is pretty much the same question as presented here:
[dynamically add plots to web page using shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875786/dynamically-add-plots-to-web-page-using-shiny)

But instead of producing a variable number of plots (which I've successfully done), I am trying to upload a selection of images into the application and display them on the user interface.  Using the same approach as described in the question above, I've produced my application with the code below.  But only the first image is rendering in the UI.

What obvious thing have I missed today?

R 3.2.2 (Windows 7)
shiny 0.12.2

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$files <- renderTable(input$files)

  files <- reactive({
    files <- input$files
    files$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", files$datapath)
    files
  })


  output$images <- renderUI({
    image_output_list <- 
      lapply(seq_along(nrow(files())),
             function(i)
             {
               imagename = paste0("image", i)
               imageOutput(imagename)
             })

    do.call(tagList, image_output_list)
  })

  observe({
    for (i in seq_along(nrow(files())))
    {
      local({
        my_i <- i
        imagename = paste0("image", my_i)
        output[[imagename]] <- 
          renderImage({
            list(src = files()$datapath[my_i],
                 alt = "Image failed to render")
          }, deleteFile = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = 'files', 
                label = 'Select an Image',
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept=c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('files'),
      uiOutput('images')
    )
  )
))
```

[image: Image1.PNG]
[image: Image2.JPG]
[image: Image3.JPEG]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your so close! Try this:

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$files <- renderTable(input$files)

  files <- reactive({
    files <- input$files
    files$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", files$datapath)
    files
  })


  output$images <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    image_output_list <- 
      lapply(1:nrow(files()),
             function(i)
             {
               imagename = paste0("image", i)
               imageOutput(imagename)
             })

    do.call(tagList, image_output_list)
  })

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    for (i in 1:nrow(files()))
    {
      print(i)
      local({
        my_i <- i
        imagename = paste0("image", my_i)
        print(imagename)
        output[[imagename]] <- 
          renderImage({
            list(src = files()$datapath[my_i],
                 alt = "Image failed to render")
          }, deleteFile = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })

})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = 'files', 
                label = 'Select an Image',
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept=c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('files'),
      uiOutput('images')
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I changed seq_along to just `1:nrow(files())` but `seq_len(nrow(files()))` or `seq_along(t(files()))` would work to.

Comment: Brilliant.  I see it now.  Thanks so much for your time.