# Dynamically create interactive plots with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created a shiny app with a dynamic number of plots, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875786/dynamically-add-plots-to-web-page-using-shiny) question. It should serve as an overview over a number of results - and now I would like to add the possibility to (double) click on one plot, in order to do something (e.g. display only this one with more details).

I had a look at the tutorial for [interactive plots](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html). However, I cannot figure out where to put the *listener* for the click input events in my code. They always return NULL, which I presume is due to the fact that the code is executed, before the plots are being generated. Here is how I create the plots:

```
createPlots <- reactive ({
  numberOfFiles <- length(densityResult)

  if (numberOfFiles == 0)
    return(NULL)
  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  for (i in filesAnalyzed) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname <- paste("densityPlot", my_i, sep="")
      result <- densityResult[[my_i]]
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(result$data, main=my_i, pch=19,cex=0.2, col= ColoursUsed[result$clusters])
        dev.off()
      })
    }
  })
})

output$plots <- renderUI({

  createPlots()

  plot_output_list <- lapply(1:length(filesAnalyzed), function(i) {
    plotname <- paste("densityPlot", filesAnalyzed[i], sep="")
    plotOutput(plotname, dblclick = dblclickOpts(id = paste(plotname, "_click", sep = "")))
  })

  # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
  # to display properly.
  do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
})
```

I created a text output for testing, which should display the *id* of the selected plot:

```
  output$click_info <- renderUI({
    numberOfPlots <- length(densityResult)
    lapply(1:numberOfPlots, function(i) {
      renderText(input[[paste("densityPlot", names(densityResult)[i], "_click", sep = "")]])
    }) 
  })
```

However, as I said before, the result is either NULL or, like in this case, the element is just not being diplayed at all. (I tried different versions, even hard-coding the name of the first input element). Using RStudios debugging, I could follow up that the code is run before the plots are created. How can I access the input elements **after** the plots have been generated?

*Edit: A minimal example can be found [here](https://benedikt.shinyapps.io/Test/).*

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and we'd be happy to help

Comment: [Here](https://benedikt.shinyapps.io/Test/) is minimal example. Sorry about that.